# Viewpager with tabs android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I want to provide tab navigation with swipe facility. For that i have tried [THIS](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator).

Link which shows tabs with viewpager. The class TestFragment.java is adding static views and class can be found at this link : [Here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/TestFragment.java)
But i want to add dynamic views.Is it possible ?
Please suggest how to implement it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar where I created the basic fragment layouts, then called a function inside the fragment from the `FragmentActivity` which then updated the view.

The easiest way to do it is to have a public method such as `updateFragment(data)` or similar in the Fragment, and call that from the parent `FragmentActivity`. The fragment can then access it's own layout using `this.getView()`

**Edit:**
So an example structure for your code might be:

```
Class FragmentActivity {

    method updateFragments() {
        Fragment myFrag = fragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
        myFrag.updateView("This is my new example string to display on the page");
    }
}

Class Fragment {
    public method updateView(String newData) {
        ((TextView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(newData);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you pleaze post your code ?? i am too confused. can you refer that github project so that it will be easier for me to understand.

Comment: I don't have any github code, but I'll post some examples to show you what I mean. IMO giving complete sets of code never helps anyone, but I'll give you some structure

Comment: Thanks..I included github project link in my question.

Comment: Aah, right I get what you mean with the github link now. I'll take a look, but I've posted some pseudo code